yaml multiline value with comments in between
I would like to do something like the following:
myKey: 
    "111,\ #comment 1
    222,\ #comment 2
    333" #comment 3


which should turn into
myKey: "111,222,333"

Is this possible or what would be the best way to accomplish this?

From the YAML 1.2.2 specs on comments: "Comments must not appear inside scalars, but may be interleaved with such scalars inside collections." (Strings, regardless of the number of line breaks they contain, are scalars, and collections are only sequences or mappings.)

What's the context for this?  You tagged this with [tag:kubernetes-helm]; is this in the context of a Helm chart, or its template code, or its values file, or something else?  Or are you generically asking how to embed comments in the middle of a multi-line YAML string, independent of Helm?

@DavidMaze We are deploying to kubernetes with helm charts using templates with values file, but I guess it's more of a generic question.

This is not possible within YAML. Not one kind of YAML scalars (double-quoted, single-quoted, plain, literal, folded) allows comments between content.
In the context of Helm, it is not possible in values.yaml because, according to the docs,

Values files are plain YAML files.

Templating in values.yaml has been proposed and rejected multiple times.
In a Helm template however, you can use template comments:
myKey: 
    "111,\ {{- /* comment 1 */}}
    222,\ {{- /* comment 2 */}}
    333" {{- /* comment 3 */}}

